# sh in docker image does not see executable on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, sh, executable

I have a docker image https://github.com/carnellj/spmia-chapter1 which does not find its CMD ./run.sh executable although it is there in the file system.

I was able to run /bin/sh in the container, and I can ls -l:

```
D:\Dokumente\ws\spring-microservices\spmia-chapter1 (master)
λ docker run -i -t johncarnell/tmx-simple-service:chapter1 /bin/sh
/ # ls -l
total 56
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Mar  3 11:20 bin
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           360 Apr 22 07:10 dev
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Apr 22 07:10 etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Mar  3 11:20 home
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Apr 22 06:01 lib
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Mar  3 11:20 media
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Mar  3 11:20 mnt
dr-xr-xr-x  123 root     root             0 Apr 22 07:10 proc
drwx------    1 root     root          4096 Apr 22 07:10 root
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Mar  3 11:20 run
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           245 Apr 22 06:50 run.sh
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Mar  3 11:20 sbin
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Mar  3 11:20 srv
dr-xr-xr-x   13 root     root             0 Apr 22 07:10 sys
drwxrwxrwt    2 root     root          4096 Mar  3 11:20 tmp
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Mar  7 01:04 usr
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Mar  7 01:04 var
/ # ./run.sh
/bin/sh: ./run.sh: not found
/ # ls run.sh
run.sh
```

/bin/sh does not find ./run.sh although it is there in the file system, as proven by ls run.sh. Also, cat shows the content of run.sh:

```
/ # cat run.sh                                                       
#!/bin/sh                                                            
echo "********************************************************"      
echo "Starting simple-service "                                      
echo "********************************************************"      
java -jar /usr/local/simple-service/simple-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

When I run vi from sh and copy the content of run.sh into a new file myrun.sh and make myrun.sh executable, I can execute ./myrun.sh and the spring service starts.

What is going on here? Why would sh not see an executable which is there in the filesystem? Executables from PATH or executables which I add manually run fine.

I am running Docker on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK the reason is, run.sh is created with Windows line endings in the docker image if you check out with automatic lf->crlf conversion. One possible solution is to tell git not to convert line endings.